# Choosing delta for continuity

Tags: real-analysis

consider the $h(x,y) = d(x,y)/(1+d(x,y)$. $(X,h)$ and $(Y,d)$ are metric spaces. I want to show functions $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow X$, are continuous.    **EDIT: $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=x$**

-For $g$ it's simple, we have $\delta/(\delta+1)$ so we can choose $\delta=\epsilon$.

-What about f? So, for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta $that if $h(x,y)<\delta $then we should have $d(x,y)<\epsilon$. I'm thinking of rearranging the above so we get $d(x,y) = h(x,y)/(1-h(x,y))$. so $d(x,y)<\delta/(1-\delta)<\epsilon$. I think we should choose $\epsilon/(\epsilon+1)$. 1-Is this correct? 2- What if I choose $\delta=\epsilon+1$ Is this correct and if not what's the problem?

Comment: You mean $(X, h)$ and $(X, d)$ are metric spaces, right?

Comment: Suppose they are metric spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the continuity of $f$ is seen easier if you use the sequence definition of continuity in metric spaces. Both approaches work, but this one involves less fussing over a choice of $\delta$. If $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $(X, h)$, this precisely says that $h(x_n, x) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Then clearly $$\frac{h(x_n, x)}{1 - h(x_n, x)} \rightarrow 0.$$ But, as you noted, $$d(x_n, x) = \frac{h(x_n, x)}{1 - h(x_n, x)},$$ which shows that that $d(x_n, x) \rightarrow 0$, and hence that $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $(X, d)$. This demonstrates that $f$ is continuous.

As for your choices of $\delta$, using $\delta = \epsilon + 1$ surely won't work, since the 1-ball of any point in $(X, h)$ is the entirety of $X$. However, taking $$\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon + 1}$$ does work once you plug into the rearrangements you made, since $$\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon + 1} * \frac{1}{1 - \frac{\epsilon}{1 + \epsilon}} = \frac{\epsilon}{(\epsilon + 1) - \epsilon} = \epsilon.$$